# Attachment field not mapped correctly in Nest 2

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, mono, nest

Trying to map an attachment attribute like this:

```
client.Map<Case>(m => m.UpdateAllTypes());
```

With this classes and mapping definitions:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "cases")]
public class Case
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string CaseName { get; set; }
    [Attachment(Store = true)]
    public Attachment File { get; set; }

}


public class Attachment
{
    [String(Name = "_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Resulted in this generated mapping

```
"mappings": {
  "cases": {
    "properties": {
      "author": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "case_name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "file": {
        "properties": {
          "_content": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "_content_type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "_name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Yep, there is `"type": "attachment"` missing down the file property definition.

Using Elasticsearch 2.2, Nest 2.0.2, Mono / .Net 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mapping worked after [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1826) was fixed:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "cases")]
public class Case
{
    public Case()
    {
    }

    [String(Name = "case_name")]
    public string CaseName { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "md5")]
    public string Md5 { get; set; }

    [Attachment(Name="file")]
    public Attachment File { get; set; }

}


public class Attachment
{
    public Attachment()
    {

    }

    [String(Name = "_author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content_lenght")]
    public long ContentLength { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [Date(Name = "_date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_keywords")]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

}
```